# Programming eclipse plugin in C#.NET

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, plugins

I have an idea for an eclipse plugin. However, my preferred language of coding is C#.NET.

I want to integrate my plugin with an existing Eclipse plugin. My question is two fold.

One, is it possible to write an eclipse plugin in C#? If so, how do I integrate it with eclipse? Keep in mind that it has to be platform independent. That is, it should work on Linux too.

Two, Is it possible to call my C# code from eclipse when some event is triggered?

Comment: The Eclipse IDE is written in Java, and its plugins are expected to be as well. That doesn't mean you couldn't write a C# program or service that you could install separately on the user's machine and have the plugin interact with it, but I think you'll find that rather cumbersome, and against your platform independence requirement. That said, programming languages shouldn't be treated like spoken languages -- they are just a tool. The best tool for this job should be used in this situation, and that's Java.

Comment: you want to make a .NET app platform independent. I have to tell you when you start going in complexity even a windows running under parallel on Mac (not clone Mac) has .net errors that normal clone pc on windows don't. With massively deployed application i have seen on the course of my dev/tech support experience issue with Mono that does not exist on windows pc platform either. That said if you know well enough C# you can most likely code your thing in Java directly. I learned Java after C# and took me a day or 2. On simple stuff, the syntax is 99% the same as C#.